# Issue when UPSERTing a record to Zoho CRM

Tags: zoho

I'm trying to use the [Record Upsert API](https://www.zoho.com/crm/help/api/v2/#ra-insert-or-update) and am running into problems with how to specify the proper duplicate check fields.

I'm using cURL, and can't figure out where you want me to include the `duplicate_check_fields` parameters

I tried putting it in the URL:

`https://www.zohoapis.com/crm/v2/contacts/upsert?duplicate_check_fields=Contacts-Email,Last_name`

And in the data, both inside and outside of the data array:

```
{  
   "data":[  
      {  
         "Company":"<COMPANY>",
         "Last_Name":"<LAST_NAME>",
         "First_Name":"<FIRST_NAME>",
         "Phone":"<PHONE NUMBER>"
      }
   ],
   "duplicate_check_fields":"Contacts - Email,Last_Name"
}
```

or

```
{  
   "data":[  
      {  
         "Company":"CTM",
         "Last_Name":"<LAST_NAME>",
         "First_Name":"<FIRST_NAME>",
         "Phone":"<PHONE NUMBER>",
         "duplicate_check_fields":"Contacts - Email,Last_Name"
      }
   ]
}
```

When I place it in either location in JSON the server responds with:

`{"code":"INVALID_DATA","details":{"expected_data_type":"jsonobject"},"message":"body","status":"error"}`

I am stumped as to what I'm missing with what should be a fairly straight forward task.

Answer (score 0):

Please give proper data and field name(api). Maybe `Contacts - Email` is not field name, it should be `Email` or `Contacts_-_Email`. You see field api name by `getFields`

Try This :

```
{  
   "data":[  
      {  
         "Company":"CTM",
         "Last_Name":"<LAST_NAME>",
         "First_Name":"<FIRST_NAME>",
         "Phone":"<PHONE NUMBER>",
         "duplicate_check_fields":"Email,Last_Name"
      }
   ]
}
```

This is my code and it's working for me ...

```
{
    "data": [{
        "Email":"teestemail@gmail.com",
        "Last_Name":"Lead Update Upsert",
        "Phone":"+884465",
        "duplicate_check_fields ":"Email,Last_Name"
    }]
}
```